# Corrrect way to mock a property in a namespace

Tags: typescript, mocking, ts-jest

I'm trying to test the following code, is there a way that I can mock the horaActual and luzNatural properties?

```js
import dayjs, { Dayjs, OpUnitType } from 'dayjs';

export namespace Tiempo {

    let horaActual = dayjs().set("hour", 6).set("minute", 0).set("second", 0);
    let luzNatural = 1;

    export function obtenerHora(): string {
        return horaActual.format("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    export function avanzar(valor: number, unidad: OpUnitType = "millisecond"): Dayjs {
        horaActual = horaActual.add(valor, unidad);
        recalcularLuzNatural();
        return horaActual;
    }
    
    function recalcularLuzNatural(): void {
        const minutos = horaActual.minute() + (horaActual.hour() * 60);
        if(minutos >= 300 && minutos < 480) {
            luzNatural = 0.00635199 * Math.pow(1.01059529, minutos);
        }else if(minutos >= 1080 && minutos < 1260) {
            luzNatural = 2.14833262E+37 * Math.pow(minutos, -12.30691935);
        }else if(minutos >= 1260 || minutos < 300) {
            luzNatural = 0.1;
        }else {
            luzNatural = 1;
        }
    }

    export function obtenerLuzNatural(): number {
        return luzNatural;
    }

}
```

I tried making a manual mock like this

```js
jest.mock("../../../src/utils/tiempo/Tiempo", () => {
    const original = jest.requireActual("../../../src/utils/tiempo/Tiempo");
    const mock = original.Tiempo;
    mock.horaActual = dayjs().set("hour", 0).set("minute", 0).set("second", 0);
    return {
        Tiempo: mock,
    };
});
```

But whenever I call the obtenerHora function it returns the real horaActual property, not the mock.
This is an example of a test I made:

```js
describe('obtenerHora', () => {

    it('Sin cambiar la hora inicial | devuelve la hora inicial', () => {
        console.log(Tiempo);
        const expectedTime = '00:00:00';
        expect(Tiempo.obtenerHora()).toBe(expectedTime);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide an example of the test code?

Comment: Of course, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things to mention here.

If I'm not mistaken you're getting the actual property because you are doing exactly that when assigning `const mock = original.Tiempo`.

But if you're testing the namespace and its functions, you *should not* mock them. You're supposed to [mock the objects that are "helping" your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) but could be "problematic" dependencies. In your example, `dayjs` could be a good candidate to be mocked.

I don't know why you encapsulated the code like that (I would think of it as a class instead, probably), but setting that aside, your test reads something like "without changing the initial time", but in your mock you're changing it. I guess that's not a good idea and it's hard to keep track of that, as you're beginning to rely on implementation details rather than behavior (like the functions being exposed).

If you control that source code, I would try to test only the functions, and be sure of what your initial conditions are (your code sets a specific initial time). And if you need it to be like it is, probably adding a function to **set** the time would also be valuable and useful.